# HTTP Post binary file in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a component that accepts dropped files (images), and then can upload them to the server.

```
export class MyComp {
  function save() {
    let data : ArrayBuffer = this.readFile(this.file);
    this.imageService.upload(data);
  }
}
```

The service POST the data to the server as a binary content (content-type is image/png).

```
@Injectable()
export class ImageService {
    private http: Http;

    constructor(@Inject()http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }
    upload(image: ArrayBuffer) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
        //let arr = new Int16Array(image);
        //let body = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arr);
        return this.http
            .put('/upload', body, { headers: headers })
            .map(response => response.json());
    }
```

The problem is that I don't arrive to send binary data (ArrayBuffer). I try to send the ArrayBuffer (it sends a string "ArrayBuffer" !), to send a Int16Array (it send a lot more bytes), to convert to string... but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Those methods are not yet implemented; check source for [request](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f2c7946cca76ab0013970b9cb013db928072fecb/modules/angular2/src/http/static_request.ts) and [response](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f2c7946cca76ab0013970b9cb013db928072fecb/modules/angular2/src/http/static_response.ts).

```
export class Request {
  // TODO: support URLSearchParams | FormData | Blob | ArrayBuffer
}
export class Response {
  // TODO: Support ArrayBuffer, JSON, FormData, Blob
}
```